# How to cancel Libreoffice UNO API Library process of convertion of ms office files to PDF in case it is over maximum permitted time

Tags: java, libreoffice, java.util.concurrent, uno

I am using UNO API Library (Soffice) from Libreoffice 6.0 to convert ms office formats to PDF, the Soffice process serves multiple sumultanious requests in server mode. 
Usually the convertion is fast, but while converting some large files, e.g. xlsx or pptx, the Soffice process uses 100% CPU and convertion takes up to a few minutes.
This is unacceptable, because during this time concurrent requests are not treated.

To handle this situation I tried to use java.util.concurrent to execute some subtasks as threads with timeout control via future interface. But it works good only if hanging occured on original ms office document load stage of convertion.
If process of convertion has already started, even though timeout exception occures, Soffice process does not quit 100% load at once, but contimue to convert document to pdf.
Program execution pauses trying to dispose loaded document.

SOffice process is started under linux via command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice, --nologo, --nodefault, --norestore, --nocrashreport, --nolockcheck, --accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;");
```

Code for convertion ms office file to pdf in simplified form is:

```
public  void  convertFile(){
xRemoteContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooPath);
xRemoteServiceManager = xRemoteContext.getServiceManager();
Object desktop = null;
desktop = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xRemoteContext);
xComponentLoader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class, desktop);
File mfile = new File(workingDir + myTemplate);
String sUrl = pathToURL(workingDir + myTemplate);
PropertyValue[] propertiesIn;
propertiesIn = new PropertyValue[2];
propertiesIn[0] = property("ReadOnly", Boolean.TRUE);
propertiesIn[1] = property("Hidden", Boolean.TRUE);
XComponent xComp = null;
try {
//xComp = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(sUrl, "_blank", 0, propertiesIn);
//The same via timeout control
xComp = callLibreLoad(sUrl, propertiesIn);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex) {
if(xComp!= null)
xComp.dispose();
...
}
// save as a PDF
XStorable xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xComp);
PropertyValue[] propertiesOut = new PropertyValue[2];
propertiesOut[0] = property("FilterName", formatfilter);
propertiesOut[1] = property("Overwrite", Boolean.TRUE);
String myResult = workingDir + fileNameOut;
try {
//xStorable.storeToURL(pathToURL(myResult), propertiesOut);
//The same via timeout control
callLibreStore(xStorable,pathToURL(myResult), propertiesOut);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex) {
if(xComp!= null)
 xComp.dispose();
...
}
if(xComp!= null)
 xComp.dispose();
}
```

Functions callLibreLoad and callLibreStore use Future interface for timeout control:

```
private XComponent callLibreLoad(String sUrl, PropertyValue[] propertiesIn) throws Exception {
XComponent result = null;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
 public Object call() throws IllegalArgumentException, com.sun.star.io.IOException {
 return xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(sUrl, "_blank", 0, propertiesIn);
 }
};
Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
try {
 result = (XComponent) future.get(maxTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} 
finally 
{ future.cancel(true);} 
return result;
}

private void callLibreStore(XStorable xStorable, String sUrl, PropertyValue[] propertiesOut) throws Exception {
Integer result = null;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
try {
xStorable.storeToURL(sUrl, propertiesOut);
} catch (com.sun.star.io.IOException e) {
log.error(e);
}
}
};
Future future = executor.submit(task);
try {
future.get(maxTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
}
finally {
future.cancel(true); // may or may not desire this
}   
}
```

So, when timeout exception take place in function callLibreLoad, SOffice process is restored to working state at once.
But when timeout take place later, in function callLibreStore, even after timeout happens and convertion thread was intrerrupted, SOffice process stays in 100% load state for more than a minute trying to dispose loaded document, executing code xComp.dispose().
At this period the stack trace of java thread with SOffice process contains following:

```
State: WAITING on com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue@30af74b8
Total blocked: 455  Total waited: 1 967
Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.removeJob(JobQueue.java:207)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:316)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:289)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:81)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:618)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:145)
com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:129)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy211.close(Unknown Source)
com.componentplus.prom.libreoffice.LibreOfficeStationary.closeDocument(LibreOfficeStationary.java:425)
com.componentplus.prom.libreoffice.LibreOfficeStationary.convertFile(LibreOfficeStationary.java:393)
...
```

How is it possible to force Soffice to cancel convertion to pdf in case it takes more than maximum permited time.

Comment: It is clearly, that a thread of file convertion is started at another process (soffice.bin) and it is not possible to interrupt that thread of external process. So I suppose the problem has no decision.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to save the `Process` instance returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, e.g. in a variable `myProc`, and then call `myProc.destroy()` to kill the process when needed.

Comment: I tried to destroy Process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/usr/lib64/libreoffice/program/soffice, --nologo, --nodefault, --norestore, --nocrashreport, --nolockcheck, --accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;) 
Soffice.bin remains in process list and becomes unusable till it is killed.

Comment: Bummer. On the slim chance that you might find something else in there that would help, the answer was based on info from Oracle's pages on the [Runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) classes.

Comment: Just realized something... I think it should be something like `Process myProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` rather than `Process=Runtime...`, and then later `myProc.destroy()`. But that's probably what you already tried and I'm just misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: As you could see above, soffice.bin process started at socket mode. Besides, soffice.bin is not java process, when you call Process myProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) to start libreoffice, myProc variable is not soffice.bin process, but some auxiliary process, and destorying  myProc we do not destroy soffice.bin process.

Comment: But the worst is, that after document has been loaded via xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL and we have started document convertion by xStorable.storeToURL,  soffice.bin process remains busy with convertion untill it is finished even if you try to abort it by all possible means, including destroy of myProc or closing document via available interface methods.

Comment: As about misunderstanding it was funny, I was typing code from head not just by copying, and of course I meant Process myProc = and not Process=Runtime...

Comment: Got that soffice.bin isn't a Java process. My thought was that the returned Process object may have stored a pointer or handle to the process it started within the system and would send to the system a call to kill it on call to destroy(). Apparently not.

Comment: Yes, and It is not a problem to destroy soffice.bin process just by command "kill processnumber" in OS, but I can not afford this as the process treats multiple  concurrent requests and beeing killed may produce multiple errors.